# query from multiple databases using in-memory database

Tags: sql, database, hsqldb, h2, in-memory-database

How to write below inner join query using in-memory database such as H2 db.

```
select * from emp e inner join other_db.dept d on e.id=d.eid
```

emp table is created in db1 database and dept table is created in other_db database.

Problem with in-memory db is that database name is not associated with data-source. So, we cannot use other_db.dept in the query.

As suggested by Thomas Mueller, please find below code written in Java and Spring framework with LINKED TABLE

Spring configuration file:

```
<jdbc:embedded-database id="db1DataSource" type="H2">
    <jdbc:script location="classpath:schema-db1.sql" />
</jdbc:embedded-database>

<jdbc:embedded-database id="otherdbDataSource" type="H2">
    <jdbc:script location="classpath:schema-other.sql" />
</jdbc:embedded-database>
```

schema-db1.sql

```
SET MODE MSSQLServer

CREATE TABLE emp ( id int NOT NULL, name varchar(30) NOT NULL)

CREATE LINKED TABLE other_db ('org.h2.Driver', 'jdbc:h2:mem:test', 'sa', '', 'dept')
```

schema-other.sql

```
SET MODE MSSQLServer

CREATE TABLE dept ( id int NOT NULL, name varchar(20) NOT NULL, eid int NOT NULL)
```

Now, can I write below query:

```
select * from emp e inner join other_db.dept d on e.id=d.eid
```

Infact, I am getting below exception on running the code:

```
Table dept not found
```

Comment: Run each one separately and join them afterwards with application code.  The details depend on the programming language.

Comment: yes I am doing that temporarily. I am using H2 in-memory database for unit testing. splitting the query in two parts to make it testable is not good approach.

Comment: @Vikas Sharma - in your updated question you have only one datatabase URL (`jdbc:h2:mem:test`). What is the other database URL?

Comment: Can you please help me with the changes need to do in the above Spring configuration to create 2 in-memory H2 databases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created two schemas under same database, using INIT property in the h2 url as shown below:

```
<bean class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
    destroy-method="close" id="db1DataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.h2.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:h2:mem:test;INIT=CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS first_db\;SET SCHEMA first_db" />
    <property name="username" value="sa" />
    <property name="password" value="" />
</bean>

<jdbc:initialize-database data-source="db1DataSource">
    <jdbc:script location="classpath:schema-db1.sql" />
</jdbc:initialize-database>

<bean class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
    destroy-method="close" id="otherdbDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.h2.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:h2:mem:test;INIT=CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS other_db\;SET SCHEMA other_db" />
    <property name="username" value="sa" />
    <property name="password" value="" />
</bean>

<jdbc:initialize-database data-source="otherdbDataSource">
    <jdbc:script location="classpath:schema-other.sql" />
</jdbc:initialize-database>
```

Now, able to run below qyery:

```
select * from emp e inner join other_db.dept d on e.id=d.eid
```

Answer (score 1):

H2 supports [Linked Tables](http://h2database.com/html/advanced.html#linked_tables) to access tables in another database. If you create a linked table first, you can then use it as you did in the query in your question. It doesn't matter if the source and / or target database is in-memory or not.

The table name is case sensitive in the same way as database metadata identifiers, so if you create a table like this in H2: `CREATE TABLE dept`, then the linked table needs to be uppercase:

```
CREATE LINKED TABLE other_db
('org.h2.Driver', 'jdbc:h2:mem:test', 'sa', '', 'DEPT')
```

Comment: With Linked tables, we cannot write query like: select * from emp e inner join other_db.dept d on e.id=d.eid. With Linked tables, we can create link of other_db.dept and write query like: select * from emp e inner join dept d on e.id=d.eid. I am using H2 in-memory database for writing unit tests. And, using SQL Server on actual production code that does not support Linked tables.

Comment: If you put the linked table in a schema called `other_db`, you can write the query as `select * from emp e inner join other_db.dept d on e.id=d.eid`.

Comment: I might be missing some point. I have updated the question with code written using LINKED table.